# How to add css using the Preprocess_image function?

Tags: 7, media, theming

I'm trying to preprocess my image style like this example

`<img class="media-object img-rounded img-responsive"  src="http://placehold.it/350x250">`

My preprocess_image function looks like so:

```
function bootstrap_subtheme_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
  if(isset($variables['style_name'])) {
    if($variables['style_name'] == 'logged-in') {
      $variables['attributes']['class'][] = "media-object";
      $variables['attributes']['class'][] = "img-responsive";
      $variables['attributes']['class'][] = "img-rounded";
    }
  }
}
```

But it is not adding the classes.

Why not?

Comment: Note that only images that are theme'd with a `theme('image')` call will work in this way. Regular `<img>` tags won't.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_image(&$variables) {
   if(isset($variables['style_name'])) {
    if($variables['style_name'] == 'image_style') // this is an image style used in drupal's image styles {
     $variables['class']['img-responsive'][] = "true";
  }
 }
}
```